# Prove that $2^n +1$ in never a perfect cube

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

**Prove that $2^n +1$  in never a perfect cube**

I've been thinking about this problem, but I don't know how to do it. I know that if $m^3=2^n+1$, then  $m$ should be an odd number, but I 'm not able to get to a contradiction.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Suppose that $2^n+1=m^3$. Then
$$2^n=m^3-1=(m-1)(m^2+m+1),$$
so each of $m-1$ and $m^2+m+1$ is a power of $2$.

But $m^2+m+1$ is odd, and therefore $m^2+m+1=1$.  That forces $m^2+m=0$, giving $m=0$ (impossible) or $m=-1$ (also impossible).

Comment: I factored it as you did, and recognized that $m^2 + m + 1$ was odd, but didn't connect the rest.  Duh on me.

Comment: Actually, hold on: "... and therefore $m^2 + m + 1 = 1$"?  I don't follow that.  Maybe: "$= 1 \text { mod } 2$"?

Comment: There is only one odd power of $2$, namely $2^0$, which is $1$. That's why $m^2+m+1=1$.   (Since we were using the same "algebra," the difference is that I am concentrating on the "power of $2$" part.)

Comment: @AndréNicolas Ahh, of course. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. It is a matter of concentrating on "numbers" rather than formulas.

Answer (score 6):

Andre's answer is neat, I've got a similar solution. Assume $m^3 = 2^n + 1$ then $m$ is odd therefore $m=2p+1$ thus $$8p^3 + 12p^2 + 6p + 1 = 2^n + 1 \implies 2p(4p^2 + 6p + 3) = 2^n$$ Note that $2p$ **and** $4p^2 + 6p + 3$ must be powers of $2$, however the latter is odd. Then, again $4p^2 + 6p + 3=1 \implies p=-1 \text{ or } p=-1/2$ both of which are impossible because $m > 0$